# See decorated Django view names in NewRelic

Tags: django, newrelic, python-decorators

All my django view methods have python decorators, which makes NewRelic show the wrapper method name (`wrapped`) instead of the view name. See the two bottom lines in the screenshot below.

How can this be worked around?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for New Relic, and we're aware of this issue. To avoid it, you can use the 'wraps()' decorator from the standard library 'functools' module to wrap the inner decorator function, like this:

```
import functools

def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def _decorator():
        f()
    return _decorator

@decorator
def foo():
    pass
```

See this doc for more details: https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-tips-and-tricks#decorators_and_introspection

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [functools.wrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) this will make sure the `__name__` attribute of the decorated function is not the name of the decorator (but that it keeps the name of the inner function)